# How to resolve conflicting types problem In C

Tags: c, header, dbus

I am trying to re-use BlueZ code in my own C program to manage Bluetooth connection and running into compilation issues.

When I analyzed the problem further here is what I think is happening:

It all comes down to my program structure:

```
1.myadv.c includes myadv.h includes gio.h
2. myadv.c includes "gdbus.h" (Helper lib)
```

Now the problem is gdbus.h has certain symbol definitions (typedef, methods etc...) that conflict with internal defs in gio.h

Because of that I get compiler errors like this:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:1383:3: error: conflicting types for ‘GDBusSignalFlags’
 } GDBusSignalFlags;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

conflicting types for ‘g_dbus_proxy_new’
 void             g_dbus_proxy_new
```

What is the best practice to avoid such symbol conflict errors during inclusion? Please note, I need to use both header files:

1. gio.h (The gnome lib)
2. gdbus.h (The dbus helper directly borrowed from BlueZ)

Comment: Is it possible to partition your code so that one file include `gio.h` and another includes `gdbus.h`, but neither includes both?  That would be the cleanest solution.  Hopefully there won't be any symbol table conflicts when you try to link the result.

Comment: @TomKarzes That may ultimately be impossible because inside adv.c I need to make two operations. One operation uses symbols from <gio.h> AND the other uses symbols from gdbus.h. E

Comment: Even if you split them up into two files and include the libs in a mutually exclusive manner, they will indirectly appear together simultaneously in a third file, correct?

Comment: @TomKarzes Still you got me thinking. Let me see what I can do in that direction.

Comment: You appear to have a deeper problem.  Not so surprisingly, I find that the BueZ sources use glib.  That explains why your two headers rely on some of the same symbols.  But that the symbol definitions do not match means that they are using *different versions* of glib.  This is unlikely to end well unless you can reconcile that difference.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your answer. The only reason for reusing some of their code is for making DBus calls to their own methods like RegisterAdvertisement. I would like to reuse their code which does all this without having to construct my own DBus object and exporting it, viz is a royal pain in C

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use the [`gdbus.h` from BlueZ](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/gdbus/gdbus.h). It’s not compatible with GLib, yet erroneously uses the GLib symbol namespace (the `g_` or `G` prefix).

Use the [GDBus API from GLib itself](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html), seeing as you’re already using GLib/GIO in your project.

Comment: Philip thanks for your answer. I am not having issues trying to use GDBus  APIs. The problem is that I am trying to incorporate code from BlueZ to ccall its well known methods like RegisterAdvertisement etc...

Comment: Coming up with DBus Advertisement object, exporting it and then invoking the RegisterAdvertisement is just boilerplate code which I hoped I could just copy paste borrow from BlueZ (gdbus.h and objects.c). Unfortunately that it turning out to be lot harder.